# Windbg "!locks" command doesn't work, can I get information anyway?

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, windbg, locks

While debugging dump files, regularly I need to check for locks, for which I use the `windbg` extension command `!locks`. When everything goes well, this provides an output like the following:

```
CritSec +54a8a8 at 0054a8a8
WaiterWoken        No
LockCount          0
RecursionCount     1
OwningThread       13d8
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0
*** Locked

CritSec +b73a8d at 00135e8d
WaiterWoken        No
LockCount          0
RecursionCount     1
OwningThread       55f3
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0
*** Locked

...

Scanned 662 critical sections
```

Sometimes, however, I get following error message:

```
Stopped scanning because of problem reading critical section debug info

Scanned 7 critical sections
```

Is it possible to have some information anyway? (E.g. where is that `critical section debug info`, how can I read it without the `!locks` command, ...)

Comment: You can try `!cs -s -l -o` but you probably will see the same thing, you may need to enable user mode stack trace using glags `!gflag +ust`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better alternative to `!locks` is to use `!cs -s -l -o` see [`!cs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-cs) this will display all locked critical sections, the owner stack trace and the critical section stack trace, you can omit the `-l` if you want all critical sections. You may need to enable the user mode stack trace using `gflags` `!gflag +ust` remember to remove it when it isn't needed `!glag -ust`.

To display critical section info, you can do this if you have the address: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/displaying-a-critical-section

so `!critsec ADDRESS` or using display type command `dt` `dt RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION ADDRESS` will work if you have the address.

Comment: Thank you. Actually !cs -l is closer to !locks, and then you can display the call stack with whatever options you want.